# Is it possible to run a jar file in an android application?

Tags: java, android

I am a begginer in android and I want to develop an application which show a list of jar files to user and user can choose one of them and run it. Is it possible to run a jar file in an android application? (not as a library)

Answer (score 1):

Nope we cannot run a jar file on android devices, You see we have `.apk` to install it on our android device. But not `.jar`, Also `Android` uses the `Dalvik VM`, where as you need the `Java VM` to run a jar-file. So you can run jar on android.

Comment: that was the point i worry about. I actually want to develop an application to show some executive file to user and user click on it to run. which file i can use as an executive file?